# How do I list a users input in while loop?

Tags: java, list, loops, input, while-loop

I want my code to list the user input, i.e. every integer, Problem is it only lists the last user input.We haven't used array in my class so I use it to solve the problem. The program will print a a line that list each integer followed by a comma and then print the sum on a different line. Please help.

```
import java.util.*;

public class InputSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int data;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in );
        System.out.println("Enter an interger (The input end if it is -1): ");
        data = input.nextInt();
        double y = data;

        int sum = -1;
        while (data != -1) {
            sum += data;
            System.out.println(
                "Enter an interger (The input end if it is -1): ");
            data = input.nextInt();


        }

        System.out.print(data + ", ");
        System.out.println("The sum:" + (sum + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output String can be built during the loop, adding each number with comma.
at the end, the whole String can be printed :

```
import java.util.*;

public class InputSum {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int data;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter an interger (The input end if it is -1): ");
      data = input.nextInt();
      double y =data;
      // constructing a string for output
      StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
      int sum = 0;
      while (data != -1){
         sum+= data;
         // adding each number to the output String
         sb.append(data + ",");
         System.out.println(
            "Enter an interger (The input end if it is -1): ");
         data = input.nextInt();
      }
      sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
      // the output is not a number, its a String
      System.out.print(sb.toString());
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("The sum:" + sum);
   }
}
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for , Thank you now I need to study your method. Moderators this question can be closed and marked as answered.

Answer (score 3):

You call

```
  System.out.print(data +", ");
```

only once at the end so it prints only the last input. You should add it to your `while` loop, just before call to `data = input.nextInt();`. Also, you don't need the `y` variable in this example and `sum` should be initialized to `0` not `-1` to make the code easier to read.

```
public class InputSum {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int data;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter an interger (The input end if it is -1): ");
      data = input.nextInt();

      int sum = 0;
      while (data != -1){
         sum+= data;
         System.out.println(
            "Enter an interger (The input end if it is -1): ");
         System.out.print(data +", ");
         data = input.nextInt();


      }
      System.out.println("The sum:" + sum);
   }
}
```

Comment: I apprecitate your help, but I need my output to look likes this     (two print lines)              Entered Number: 10, 2, 13, 50, 100
 The Sum: 175

Comment: Then print "Entered Number:" before the whole thing and change "The sum:" to "\nThe sum:". You will also have to find a way to delete additional comma after the last number :-)